# Can "They interest me" be interpreted the same as "They're interested in me"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> "They interest me"

vs.

> "They're interested in me"

Are the sentences grammatically correct? 
Is the meaning of the two sentences similar?

Answer (score 8):

They convey different ideas:
"They interest me." --> You want to know more about them.
"They're interested in me." --> They want to know more about you.